# Angular google maps always fits even if I put fit="false" using ionic

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, angular-google-maps

I have declared an angular google maps like this:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map   zoom-control-options="{style:'LARGE', position:'TOP_RIGHT'}" options="map.options" center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' events="map.events" draggable="true" data-tap-disabled="true">
<ui-gmap-markers modelsbyref="false" idkey="'id'" models="map.markers" coords="'self'" doCluster="false" fit="false" icon="'icon'" events="map.markersEvents " options="'options'">

    </ui-gmap-markers>

    <ui-gmap-polygons models="map.polys" idkey="'id'" path='"geom"' fill='"fill"'
                        stroke='"stroke"' visible="true" geodesic="true" fit="false"
                        editable="false" static="true" ng-cloak="" draggable="false">

    </ui-gmap-polygons>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Even if I try to setCenter or, change center in scope or zoom in programatically I can't make it because the map doesn't react to the changes.
Is like is always fit="true"
And when I add a marker outside the point where I initialize the marker center, the map automatically moves the screen to fit the new point, which is something I don't want it to do, I want it to keep staticon the center point.
Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance